# jQgrid tableToGrid inside jQuery UI tabs in AJAX mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid, tabs

I have an issue with jgrid's tableToGrid. I have three nested tabs (inside an another tab) that generate out of the following three list items

```
<div id='sub_nav_menu >
<ul>
<li><a href='workorders.php'/>Open WorkOrders</a><li>
<li><a href='workorders.php?status=overdue'/>Stale WorkOrders</a><li>
<li><a href='workorders.php?status=closed'/>closed WorkOrders</a><li>
</ul>
</div>
```

jQuery-ui will create a content div for each one of these links in an unobtrusive manner, where the result obtained from the server will be shown inside that div as a table, with the same class selector of the other tables obtained from selecting the other siblings tabs. The tables will be shown inside the dynamically created div, which associate with each of these tabs. The table looks like this:

```
<table class='result-table'>
<thead>...</thead>
<tbody>You know what's here ...</tbody>
</table>
```

and the jquery ui code which creates the grid is this

```
$('#nav').tabs({
    load: function() {
            // first: load the inner tabs
            $('#sub_nav_menu').tabs({
                    load: function (event,ui) {
                            // second: load jqGrid stuff after loading the tabs content 
                            tableToGrid(".result-table:eq(" + ui.index + ")",{ 
                                    defaults : {
                                    recordtext: "View {0} - {1} of {2}",
                                    emptyrecords: "No records to view",
                                    loadtext: "Loading...",
                                    pgtext : "Page {0} of {1}"
                                    },
                                    loadonce: true,
                                    rowNum: 10,
                                    caption: 'Showing "Open Work orders"' 

                             });
                    } //inner nav 'load' function
            });
    } //upper nav 'load' function
   });
```

The table is converting properly to a jqGrid, the data of the original table is carried over properly inside the plugin code in a "data" array; however, the plugin fails when it reaches to the point of

```
jQuery(this).jqGrid(jQuery.extend({
    datatype: "local",
    width: w,
    colNames: colNames,
    colModel: colModel,
    multiselect: selectMultiple
    //inputName: inputName,
    //inputValueCol: imputName != null ? "__selection__" : null
}, options || {}));
```

Which is followed by the code

```
$.fn.jqGrid = function( pin ) {
if (typeof pin == 'string') {
    //var fn = $.fn.jqGrid[pin];
    var fn = $.jgrid.getAccessor($.fn.jqGrid,pin);
    if (!fn) {
        throw ("jqGrid - No such method: " + pin);
    }
    var args = $.makeArray(arguments).slice(1);
    return fn.apply(this,args);
}
return this.each( function() { // it failes where the "chaining" happens
    if(this.grid) {return;}
```

However, the code fails where the "chaining" happens with the error code 
 Uncaught Error: Syntax Error, unrecognized expression "#"

It seems it's related to the 'class' vs. 'id' selector as when I change the table selection to 'id' it works.

I am just wondering if this could be a bug in the plugin of jqGrid. Even if it's the case, what would you suggest as a different way to go around this problem. I was thinking of generating different ids for each one of the tables, but I am just annoyed with the issue of not being able to use tables class as a selector!

The jQuery version is 1.7.1,
The jQuery-UI 1.8.17
The jqGrid is 4.3.1

Thanks alot!

**Workaround**
I managed to make it work with server-side generated ids for easier reference and then doing a switch at the client-side on these ids as they are previously known. However, I see this method as being inefficient because it don't deal with general case selectors, but rather specific ones and do not address the real problem.

Comment: I encountered the same bug. If you try to use something like this:

tableToGrid("#some_id_of_div > table");

The code fails with the error you mentioned. I think this is a bug in the tableToGrid function.